# Проблема с библиотекой tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Несколько лет назад работал с библиотекой *tkinter*. Сейчас при попытке её вызова:

```py
from tkinter import*
root=Tk()

root.mainloop()
```

-она не работает. Может я что-то делаю не так? Не подскажите, как правильно?

Comment: `from Tkinter import*` for python2

Comment: @Victor не подскажите тогда, как правильно импортировать эту библиотеку?

Comment: Какую ошибку выдает?

Comment: @Victor Такую: builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter'

Comment: Для питона три `tkinter` не `Tkinter`

Comment: Голосую за закрытие вопроса (до уточнения информации), т.к. ошибка "builtins.ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Tkinter' " не соответствует коду в вопросе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно проблема из-за того что у вас python 2, а не 3.Тогда так:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: @ Victor Нет, я абсолютно уверен, что у меня python 3,7. Можно узнать, как работать(вызвать) с tkinter  в python 3?

Comment: `from tkinter import*`

Answer (score 0):

У меня работало так: я импортировал сначала библиотеку одиночно, а после уже через from. А в root указал класс Tk() от tkinter.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

А если не работает, то может быть это уже проблемы с IDE